# New created archive on xamarin not appearing on xcode?? (distribuction build)

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin

"I have read the documentation to allow deployment of an iOS App to the AppStore using MonoTouch. Here is a link that explains the same:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution_overview/publishing_to_the_app_store/

I have been able to create the MonoTouch Archive using the 'Build Archive' option as explained. However, when I go to the XCode Organizer, I do not see my Archive in there. Is there a specific reason why this doesn't show up in Archive as documented?"

I am using xcode 4.6 and nothing is appearing...

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes happening. What cures this for me, is to close XCode and reopen. Seems more like an issue with XCode than Xamarin.Studio.